# Symfony translation get value without parameter `%count%` or any other custom paramater

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, symfony4

I have list of months names in my translation config file

**messages.en.yml:**

```
basic:
   months:
      -
      - January
      - February
      - March
      - April
      - May
      - June
      - July
      - August
      - September
      - October
      - November
      - December
```

The translation works when I do this:

```
$this->translator->trans('basic.months.'.$month);
```

But the problem here is that `php bin/console debug:translation en` gives error that translation `basic.months` is missing.

How can I fix the issue without changing the config file ?

I can try this but

```
$this->translator->trans('basic.months', ['%count%' => $month]);
```

This code doesn't work and doesn't translate the message.

Thanks.

Comment: Dont know if it's related but maybe remove the empty element from your months list in your yaml file ?

Comment: not working. Same error.

Comment: Did you check here https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#message-format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was resolved by just doing this:

```
$transId = 'basic.months.'.$month;
$this->translator->trans($transId);
```

Now no debug errors are recorded and translations work as expected

Answer (score 0):

The `bin/console debug:translation` scan all source files for **static** strings that contain message ids from your `messages.en.yml` file.

Your message id `'basic.months.'.$month` is **dynamic** and that's why `debug:translation` could not detect it. Therefore it's hardly possible to fix error without changing the config file.

I suggest using icu message format:

```php
$this->translator->trans('basic.months', ['month' =>  $month]);
```

```yaml
# translations/messages+intl-icu.en.yaml
basic:
  months: >-
    {month, select,
    1     {January}
    2     {February}
    3     {March}
    4     {April}
    5     {May}
    6     {June}
    7     {July}
    8     {August}
    9     {September}
    10    {October}
    11    {November}
    12    {December}
    other {}
    }
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/message_format.html#selecting-different-messages-based-on-a-condition